# In Racket, can I redefine the form `if` and have other derived forms automatically follow its new semantics?

Tags: macros, racket

In a custom Racket language, I would like to change the behavior of the core form `if` as well as other forms that expand to it (such as `and` and `cond`).

Naturally, I could redefine each of these forms but this seems rather redundant. For instance, here is an example where the modified `if` expects each of its arguments to be wrapped in a list. The macro `and` is here redefined explicitly.

```lisp
;; my-lang.rkt
#lang racket/base

(require (for-syntax racket/base))

(provide #%module-begin #%datum #%app
         list
         (rename-out [car-if if] [car-and and]))

(define-syntax (car-if stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ c t f) #'(if (car c) t f)]))

(define-syntax (car-and stx) ; this seems redundant
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_) #'#t]
    [(_ x) #'x]
    [(_ x xs ...) #'(car-if x (car-and xs ...) x)]))
```

```lisp
#lang s-exp "my-lang.rkt"

(if (list #f) (list 2) (list 3)) ; => (3)
(and (list #f) (list 2)) ; => (#f)
```

Is there an easier way to redefine these forms by *injecting* my new definition of `if` into the existing definitions provided by `racket/base`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no.

Let's consider the form `and`. It is defined as a macro (somewhere).
It looks something like:

```
#lang mumble
(define-syntax (and stx)
   (syntax-case stx ()
     [(_and)             #'#t]
     [(_and e)           #'e]
     [(_and e1 e2)       #'(let ([t e1]) (if t e2 #f))]
     [(_and e1 e2 e ...) #'(let ([t e1]) (if t (and e2 e ...)))]
     [_ (raise-syntax-error 'and "bad syntax" stx)]))
```

Since the Racket macro system is "referentially transparent" the
identifiers are bound using standard lexical scope rules. That is
the `if` in the expansion is bound to the `if` in the module where
the macro is defined. The point is that the macro writer doesn't 
need to fear any users redefining any identifiers used in the expansion.

The only way to change the behaviour of the `and` macro above is to 
change the `if` used. So only if you have access to the definition 
of "mumble", you can change the `if` used. In the case of the standard
Racket `and` no user can change the definitions.

In short, the answer is "no" due to the design of the macro system.